# What are current and relevant Azure projects to learn from?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

There are many Azure projects on codeplex and scattered over MSDN.  Some of them are so old that they use the code-based version of the storage client, and not the compiled version.

Which projects are current and relevant, and which are outdated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Getting Started with Azure**
http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/12/30/Essential-Resources-for-Getting-Started-with-Windows-Azure.aspx

**Current and by MSFT:**

MSDN Samples 
[Part 1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=Windows%20Azure) *Demonstrates COMET via Silverlight and WCF among other samples*
[Part 2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B0%5D.Value=Azure) *Includes HTTP compression sample*

How to... In Azure
Some entries contain code samples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg432998.aspx

FabrikamShipping
Includes AD FS Federation, Facebook integration, and provisioning automation 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/03/14/fun-with-fabrikamshipping-saas-ii-creating-an-enterprise-edition-instance.aspx

Azure SDK 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018

Azure Training Kit
Located at C:\WAPTK\Default.htm 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78

Patterns and Practices
[Cloud Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff898430.aspx) (Greenfield and Brownfield scenarios)
[Tailspin Toys Hands On Lab](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bd89a4f3-b0ff-4277-b042-e2d0ac08e9a8&displaylang=en)
Note there is a part 1 and part 2 to this
http://wag.codeplex.com/

Developing applications for the cloud
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx

All In One Samples 
Has some Azure samples for oData and more.  See both the 2008 and 2010 samples since each has different code.
http://1code.codeplex.com/

WCF Azure Samples
(looks up to date, but is located on "archive.msdn" which is disconcerting ) 
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/

**3rd Party up to date**

Encryption for Azure Table
Easily and transparently encrypt Table data
http://azuretableencrypt.codeplex.com/

Lokad.Cloud
An ORM for the cloud aka O/C mapper
http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/

Facebook
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/
http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com/

Azure Storage
http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/  (Oct of '10)

Azure Accelerators
http://azureaccelerators.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Aside from makerofthings7's thorough answer, let me add one more:

- David Pallman's '[Azure Storage Samples](http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/)' - these are complete samples with two implementations each: .NET Storage Client Library and REST. This was published in February, 2011.

Answer (score 1):

A project that probably contain all the providers you will ever need; Membership, Role, Session, and Profile providers. Stores in the Azure Table Storage and uses the Azure Queue http://azureproviders.codeplex.com